# Condition for skipping web page where data is not available

Tags: python, web-scraping, attributeerror

I'm trying to fetch data from 'http://weather.uwyo.edu/upperair/sounding.html' website. I wrote following script but the problem is some stations in given site are not having any data. So it's giving error as 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text''. I want to write some condition so that wherever data is not there it should skip that station and go for next station.

try:
    for stn in station:

```
    year = '2017'
    month = '08'
    day = '14'
    hour = '00'
    end = '12'

url = requests.get('http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=naconf&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR='+year+'&MONTH='+month+'&FROM='+day+hour+'&TO='+day+end+'&STNM='+str(stn))
```

## webbrowser.open('http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=seasia&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR='+year+'&MONTH='+month+'&FROM='+day+hour+'&TO='+day+end+'&STNM='+str(stn))

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text,'html.parser')
data_box = soup.find('pre')
data = data_box.text.strip()
print (data)
```

except AttributeError :
    print("No data available for  station", AttributeError)

```
import sys
import webbrowser
import urllib3
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

station =[42647,42101]       # [42101] #,42647,42971,43371]

try:
    for stn in station:

        year = '2017'
        month = '08'
        day = '14'
        hour = '00'
        end = '12'

    url = requests.get('http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=naconf&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR='+year+'&MONTH='+month+'&FROM='+day+hour+'&TO='+day+end+'&STNM='+str(stn))
```

## webbrowser.open('http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=seasia&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR='+year+'&MONTH='+month+'&FROM='+day+hour+'&TO='+day+end+'&STNM='+str(stn))

```
  soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text,'html.parser')
  data_box = soup.find('pre')
  data = data_box.text.strip()
 except AttributeError :
        print("No data available for  station", AttributeError)
    print (data)
```

I expect it should print data for data available stations by skipping stations where data is not available.But the output is :
No data available for  station 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sound.py", line 30, in 
    data = data_box.text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the exception handling scoping wrong; the exception is bubbled up and catched *outside* for loop, so the `for` loop already exited at that point.

You need to set the `try-except` where you think the exception could be raised inside the `for` loop i.e. choose the smallest scope:

```
for stn in station:
    ...
    try:
        data = data_box.text.strip()
     except AttributeError :
        print("No data available for  station", AttributeError)
        continue  # move onto next station
```